# How to squeeze lots of variables?

Tags: batch-file

I am setting up some code that will help me run a mathematical experiment. Is there a way to use loops in batch to create multiple variables automatically.

I have tried to join a variable to a set command (before the equal sign), but then the command does not run.

```
@echo off

set variablerep=0
pause

Set p1=0

Set p2=0

Set p3=0

...

...

Set p34=0

Set p35=0

Set p36=0



Pause
```

I hope to find ways by which I don't need to copy each set command and make minor changes and code efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `for /l` loop:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set p_

for /l %%l in ( 1, 1, 36 ) do set p_%%l=0

set p_
```

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: I have a small question, why do we put the setlocal and set p_ next to the for command?

Comment: The command `setlocal` localizes all variables declared by the script, so when the script is finished, all its variables will be destroyed. It is good practice to initialize variables before their usage and destroying when they are not needed

`set p_` is used just to illustrate.

Answer (score 2):

- Please remember that math in (pure) batch is restricted to 32bit signed integers (+/- ~2GB).
- and **NO** floating point math.
- All variables are stored as strings and only `set /A` and the `if` commands **try** to convert to integers.
- the syntax of `set /a` allows several calculatons on one line delimited with a comma,

---

```
set /A p1=0,p2=0,p3=0
```

there also is a special variant allowing to set several variables to the same value:

```
set /A p1=p2=p3=0
```

When using an index to address variables the pseudo `array[%%I]` format is common, whereas every valid naming scheme can be used - as [jsxt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53920669/6811411)s answer shows.